# Is it possible to create a condensed view of an already existing table?

Tags: microsoft-access-2013

I have a database with two tables.  The first table (Inbound) is a list of tables and their respective data fields that are used to create Output tables.  The second table (Output) is a full list of what the Output tables are (Entity Name, Table name, column names, Data Type, Attribute format, etc.). These tables are "linked" via a key so that I know which Inbound piece of information is responsible for the Output result.

I need to create a third table that we can share with others that is exactly what is in the second table, the Output table, but limits to only show a few of the fields.

The main Output table has EVERYTHING we need for a reference, but when sharing the database, I want to only show the select information for my users to see and not be bogged down or confused by the rest of the information.  The main output table has about 18 fields, but I only want the "new" table to show 10 of those fields.

Is it possible to create a condensed view of an already existing table? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does this have to be a table? Also, asking a question about the "best way" of doing something is soliciting opinions. I changed the question to meet the site requirements.

Comment: Thank you.  If not a table, what else would it be?  In the end, I do need a list type, showing all the Output information, but just for 5-6 fields.  All the other stuff is "noise" for the end user and I don't want them to see it.  So I figured just a copy of the main Output table would suffice.  I don't need anything modified or aggregated, just displayed differently.

One thing though, changes would potentially be made in this condensed view, and I need those changes, updates, edits to apply to both the condensed view table and the main Output table as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. You can;

- create a make-table query that populates the new table with the data
  you want
- run a query of the data you want them to see and display in Datasheet
  View
- create a form to display the data
- create a report to display the data

The problem with using a table is users will be able to modify the data. Personally, I would use a query. It can look just like a table in Datasheet View, but data can not be changed.

If users are to be able to change data, they will need table access. So, creating a duplicate table will not likely save the changes to the original table. In this case, a form may be a better tool.

Comment: Thank you again, I have in fact now created a make-table query and it does present the data I want to see. My next step will be to create a form to display the data.